# How to make the related list "lastModified Date" to be populated in Master Record

Tags: opportunity, formula-field, account, related-list, lastmodifieddate

There is a requirement where I need to populate the **last modified date** of Opportunity related list in Account Record  because the changes made in opportunity will be reflected only in **last modified date** for that particular opportunity Record but not for the master record.

I tried Creating a formula field but that doesn't show opportunity object in it?How can we achieve it?

[image: Account Date]

[image: Opportunity Date]

As you see opportunity date and account date seems to be different after making changes in opportunity.I want that to be updated for master account date using some other formula fields

Comment: this is not clear - please use [edit] and add an example

Comment: The dlrs package can handle rolling up the first or last value...

Comment: So you want the lastModifiedDate of the account (or a custom field) to be the lastModifiedDate of the latest updated opportunity related to that account ? I they you may want to specify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a formula field to the Account won't update it when a related opportunity is updated. You will need to add a trigger or a field update workflow rule to the Opportunity to cause the Account to be updated.

However, since you already have data populated in the system, you might be better served using a Rollup Summary field:

./package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types> 
        <members>Account.LastOpportunityUpdateDateTime__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

./objects/Account.object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>LastOpportunityUpdateDateTime__c</fullName>
        <label>Opportunity Update Date Time</label>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>Summary</type>
        <summarizedField>Opportunity.LastModifiedDate</summarizedField>
        <summaryForeignKey>Opportunity.Account</summaryForeignKey>
        <summaryOperation>Max</summaryOperation>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: But the workflow or trigger will be updated only after some operation being performed right?I want it to be updated for all all the accounts by default..

Comment: Right, you could essentially tie the account to its opportunities so that whenever an opportunity is updated, the account will also be updated. No additional action would need to be taken; when an opportunity is updated, its associated account will be updated by default.

Comment: This will happen for the account whose opportunity is recently being updated.But the old records which doesn't have any changes will be retained with the accounts last modified date na?So I want all the records to have opportunities last modified date in account

Comment: In that case: Can you do this in a different field? Does it have to be the LastModifiedDate? The LastModifiedDate field isn't really something that can be updated to an arbitrary value.

Comment: No no it can be any field.But to do that we can have only formula fields right?But it doesn't show up opportunity object in account

Comment: Formula fields can go from child to parent, roll up summaries can go from parent to child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44761/discussion-between-pri-and-martin).